# Find files of specified size using bash in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am looking for a Unix command to print the files with its size. I used this but it didn't work.

```
find . -size +10000k -print.
```

I want to print the size of the file along with the filename/directory.

Comment: That command gives me `find: unknown predicate '-print.'`  I presume the `.` isn't really there.  Precision is important.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
find . -size +10000k -exec ls -sd {} +
```

If your version of `find` won't accept the `+` notation (which acts rather like `xargs` does), then you might use (GNU `find` and `xargs`, so `find` probably supports `+` anyway):

```
find . -size +10000k -print0 | xargs -0 ls -sd
```

or you might replace the `+` with `\;` (and live with the relative inefficiency of this), or you might live with problems caused by spaces in names and use the portable:

```
find . -size +10000k -print | xargs ls -sd
```

The `-d` on the `ls` commands ensures that if a directory is ever found (unlikely, but...), then the directory information will be printed, not the files in the directory.  And, if you're looking for files more than 1 MB (as a now-deleted comment suggested), you need to adjust the `+10000k` to `1000k` or maybe `+1024k`, or `+2048` (for 512-byte blocks, the default unit for `-size`).  This will list the size and then the file name.  You could avoid the need for `-d` by adding `-type f` to the `find` command, of course.

Comment: thanks. I used  
find . -size +300000k -print | xargs ls -sd 2> /dev/null

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have GNU find:

```
find . -size +10000k -printf '%s %f\n'
```

If you want a constant width for the size field, you can do something like:

```
find . -size +10000k -printf '%10s %f\n'
```

Note that `-size +1000k` selects files of at least 10,240,000 bytes (`k` is 1024, not 1000).  You said in a comment that you want files bigger than 1M; if that's 1024*1024 bytes, then this:

```
find . -size +1M ...
```

will do the trick -- except that it will also print the size and name of files that are *exactly* 1024*1024 bytes.  If that matters, you could use:

```
find . -size +1048575c ...
```

You need to decide just what criterion you want.

Comment: You'd need a `c` after `+1048575` to get bytes (characters) instead of the default of 512-byte blocks.

Answer (score 9):

Find can be used to print out the file-size in bytes with %s as a printf. %h/%f prints the directory prefix and filename respectively. \n forces a newline.

Example

```
find . -size +10000k -printf "%h/%f,%s\n"
```

Output

```
./DOTT/extract/DOTT/TENTACLE.001,11358470
./DOTT/Day Of The Tentacle.nrg,297308316
./DOTT/foo.iso,297001116
```

Comment: Interesting.  That should be documented as a GNU extension (I assume) to the POSIX standard [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).