# how does `find' calculate the size of a file?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I tried to use `find` to find the files smaller than 2K (kilobytes), but `find . -size -2048c` and `find . -size -2k` gave totally different results.

But these two should be considered the same according to the manual.

```
`c'    for bytes
`w'    for two-byte words
`k'    for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
```

I have a bunch of files that are 1.5k or so. `-2048c` could find these files, but `-2k` gave nothing.

Comment: You're going to have to explain under what conditions you're finding different results.

Comment: @almasshaikh but 2048c means 2k right? I have to do the math if I use b.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079740/find-files-with-size-in-unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. POSIX specifies<sup>*</sup> that `find` should use only whole periods when performing a comparison, with any remainder discarded. This means that `-size -2k` will indeed not find any file with a size between 1025 and 2047 bytes.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Technically it is only specified for the block unit size determination; GNU find extends this to the kilobyte unit for consistency.</sub>

Comment: Then this means `-size -2048c` actually equal to `-size -3k`?

Comment: No, because `-size -3k` will include files 2048 bytes in size.